# Правильное условие для формулы суммесли

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
=(СУММЕСЛИ(A2:A6;A1;C2:C6)+СУММЕСЛИ(B2:B6;A1;D2:D6))/СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:A6;"*")
```

Вот так считаю сумму если слово в столбце А из ячейки А1, то суммируется колонка С, если слово в столбце В, то суммируется колонка D. Как сделать наоборот? Чтобы все это считалось не для слова из ячейки А1. Понимаю, что нужно в формулу прописать условие, но не знаю как. Что-то типа <>A1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно?

Comment: `СУММ(A2:A6) - СУММЕСЛИ(A2:A6;A1;C2:C6)`

Comment: Спасибо. Да, это хороший вариант, но хотелось бы узнать как прописать через отрицание (not A1, <>A1 что-то такое), если, конечно, в excel есть такая возможность, видимо, должна быть

Comment: Так и написать: `СУММЕСЛИ(A2:A6;"<>"&A1;C2:C6)`

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно